# MS Access cannot view all column value

Tags: ms-access

Good day,

Just want to ask if there is a way i can view the complete column value in one of the fields in my access database. It was truncated when i query the column but when i am viewing it inside the program i was able to view all the column values. I needed to display all the value of that column on my query is there a way to do it? See below images for more details of my problem. Thanks in advance.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

[image: Image4]

Comment: What do you mean by "inside the program" - the table? Is this a multi-value field or just a memo field with a very long string? Edit question to show query SQL statement. Not really clear what that those images are from - table, query, form, report?

Comment: There's a program that is consuming the .mdb when i am viewing values on the application i was able to view all the values inside that memo field (ItemFilter). But when i try to query this on ms access using simple "select * from promos" the value on that memo field (ItemFilter) is incomplete/truncated which was shown on the first image.

Comment: "There's a program" - what program? I cannot replicate issue within Access query. Since there is no code provided for analysis, this question is not really appropriate for SO.

Comment: I can send you copy of the program including the access database for you to check my issue.

Comment: Can't attach files here and won't provide email. Could post question to a forum that allows attaching files.